# How to use nextPageToken to check all files under one folder with more than 1000 files in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

Recently I carried land cover classification and export around 3000 files into one folder of the asset. However there were only 1000 files displayed on the code editor. I also used ee.data.listAssets() function and print the result. The result showed a list of 1000 elements with nextPageToken code. I wonder how to use the nextPageToken code to check the rest file ids but I did not find the resolution. Other methods which could work are also welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you do this, where `myFolder` is some folder to which you have read access:

```
var l = ee.data.listAssets(myFolder)
print(l)
print(l.nextPageToken)

var l2 = ee.data.listAssets(myFolder, {pageToken: l.nextPageToken})
print(l2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the question perfectly.